# Binding MVC4 to An Object Containing Arrays

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I am creating a form to allow employees to submit timesheets online. The form consists of a number of sections, each representing a day of the week. Within each section, the user can add multiple rows, each row reflecting a task undertaken that day.

```
function AddRow(day)
{
    var count = $("#RowCount_" + day).data("count");

    var row = "<tr>" +
                   "<td>&nbsp;</td>" +
                    "<td><input type='text' size='50' id='" + day + "[" + count + "].Description' name='timesheet." + day + "[" + count + "].Description' class='Description' data-day='" + day + "' /></td>" +
                    "<td><input type='text' size='6' id='" + day + "[" + count + "].Start' name='timesheet." + day + "[" + count + "].Start' /></td>" +
                    "<td><input type='text' size='6' id='" + day + "[" + count + "].Finish' name='timesheet." + day + "[" + count + "].Finish' /></td>" +
                    "<td><input type='text' size='6' id='" + day + "[" + count + "].Travel' name='timesheet." + day + "[" + count + "].Travel'/></td>" +
                    "<td>" +
                        "<select style='width:200px' id='" + day + "[" + count + "].JobNo' name='timesheet." + day + "[" + count + "].JobNo'>@Html.Raw(ViewBag.Jobs)</select>" +
                    "</td>" +
                    "<td><input type='text' size='6' id='" + day + "[" + count + "].Hrs' name='timesheet." + day + "[" + count + "].Hrs' /></td>" +
                "</tr>";

    $("#Table_" + day).append(row);
    $("#RowCount_" + day).data("count", ++count);
}
```

I then want to bind this to a `Timesheet` object, as follows:

```
public class Timesheet
{
    List<Core.Models.TimesheetEntry> Monday = new List<TimesheetEntry>();
    TimesheetEntry[] Tuesday { get; set; }
    TimesheetEntry[] Wednesday { get; set; }
    TimesheetEntry[] Thursday { get; set; }
    TimesheetEntry[] Friday { get; set; }
    TimesheetEntry[] Saturday { get; set; }
    TimesheetEntry[] Sunday { get; set; }
}
```

(note I am trying both lists and arrays here, neither of which bind, but more of this in a minute)

The `TimesheetEntry` is as follows:

```
public class TimesheetEntry
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Start { get; set; }
    public string Finish { get; set; }
    public decimal Travel { get; set; }
    public string JobNo { get; set; }
    public decimal Hrs { get; set; }
}
```

This posts to the following controller method:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Core.Models.Timesheet timesheet)
{
    return View();
}
```

When submitted, the form does not bind (all fields in timesheet are 0 or null). However, if I change the controller to

```
public ActionResult Create(List<Core.Models.TimesheetEntry> Monday)
{
    return View();
}
```

and adjust the name of the html fields to `name='" + day + "[" + count + "].Description'` then it will bind just fine. This is a little messy, so I'd rather use the `Timesheet` class if possible. Is there an issue binding to Lists within models?

EDIT: Below is a snippet of the post data, with a single entry and 2 blank entries for monday, 3 blank for tuesday:

```
timesheet.Monday[0].Description:test entry
timesheet.Monday[0].Start:0900
timesheet.Monday[0].Finish:1700
timesheet.Monday[0].Travel:0
timesheet.Monday[0].JobNo:14089A - line 14 hut heater sockets
timesheet.Monday[0].Hrs:7.5
timesheet.Monday[1].Description:
timesheet.Monday[1].Start:
timesheet.Monday[1].Finish:
timesheet.Monday[1].Travel:
timesheet.Monday[1].JobNo:14089A - line 14 hut heater sockets
timesheet.Monday[1].Hrs:
timesheet.Monday[2].Description:
timesheet.Monday[2].Start:
timesheet.Monday[2].Finish:
timesheet.Monday[2].Travel:
timesheet.Monday[2].JobNo:14089A - line 14 hut heater sockets
timesheet.Monday[2].Hrs:
timesheet.Tuesday[0].Description:
timesheet.Tuesday[0].Start:
timesheet.Tuesday[0].Finish:
timesheet.Tuesday[0].Travel:
timesheet.Tuesday[0].JobNo:14089A - line 14 hut heater sockets
timesheet.Tuesday[0].Hrs:
timesheet.Tuesday[1].Description:
timesheet.Tuesday[1].Start:
timesheet.Tuesday[1].Finish:
timesheet.Tuesday[1].Travel:
timesheet.Tuesday[1].JobNo:14089A - line 14 hut heater sockets
timesheet.Tuesday[1].Hrs:
```

Comment: Hi, you are facing the same issue as this post. please take a look at the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22046978/mvc-submit-form-with-partial-view/22047394#22047394

Answer (score 0):

Change all `TimesheetEntry[]` arrays to `List<TimesheetEntry>`

Try to add constuctor to your model that initialized all fields of model:

```
public class Timesheet
{
    public Timesheet()
    {
        Monday = new List<Core.Models.TimesheetEntry>();
        Tuesday  = new List<Core.Models.TimesheetEntry>();          
    }   
}
```

Make sure your post data have prefix like `Timesheet.Monday[0].Description=...`

And this'l do things

Comment: unfortunately that doesn't seem to help. All come back with a count of 0.

Comment: @GavinCoates what's your postdata look like?

Comment: see modified original post @Sergio

Answer (score 0):

Answer to this question going to be as long as it's good for a blog post. Anyways, Please do the followings

Go to Views->Shared folder and create a new folder called `EditorTemplates`

In that EditorTemplates folder, Create a partial view called _TimeSheetEntry which handles one row (one TimeSheetEntry) as follows

```
@model TimeSheetEntry
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Description)</td>
    <!--Add code for other fields-->
</tr>
```

Now in your main view, do the following.

```
@model TimeSheet
<table id="table_1">
    @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Monday.Count; i++)
    {
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Monday[i], "_TimeSheetEntry")
    }
</table>
<input type="button" onClick="addRow(1)" value="Add Row" />
<!-- Do the same for other 4 days, change the table id accordingly and pass the correct day value for addRow-->
```

Now in your controller, Create an Action that will add a new row to the table which we will call using ajax later.

```
[HttpGet]
public PartialViewResult AddTimeSheetRow(int day, int index)
{
    string prefix = "";
    switch(day)
    {
        case 1:
        prefix = "Monday[" + index + "]"
        break;
        //do the same for other 4 days but change the day name
    }
    ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix = prefix;
    return PartialView("_TimeSheetEntry", new TimeSheetEntry());
}
```

Now, lets move on to the javascript code in the `Create` view.

```
function addRow(day){
    var tbody = $("table_" + day).find('tbody');
    var index = tbody.find('tr').size() - 1;
    $.get('@Url.Action("AddTimeSheetRow", "YourControllerName")', 
          { day:day, index:index },
          function (response){
              tbody.append(response);
          });
}
```

This is a quick code I put together, there's definitely room for improvements. But above should get you started.