# Pass dynamic model to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have table which is filled with some data, when I click "addTemplate" in my controller I don't get any data from table.

Here is my index.cshtml

```
@model ReportGenerator.WebUI.Models.FieldViewModel
@{
    var list = @Model.IEnumerableField.GroupBy(item => item.TemplateName).ToList();
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("addTemplate", "TemplateField", FormMethod.Post))
        {
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <label class="label label-default">Nazwa szablonu*</label>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.field.TemplateName, new { @class = "form-control" })
                    <br /><br />
                </div>
            </div>

            <table id="sort" class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Nazwa kolumny z BD*</th>
                        <th>Długość rekordu*</th>
                        <th>Nazwa kolumny wyświetlana</th>
                        <th>Format*</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="tblsort">
                    @for (var i = 0; i < Model.listOfFormats(Model.field.TemplateName).ColumnNamesDB.Count; i++)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.listOfFormats(Model.field.TemplateName).ColumnNamesDB[i], new { @class = "form-control" })</td>
                            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.listOfFormats(Model.field.TemplateName).LengthColumns[i], new { @class = "form-control" })</td>
                            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.listOfFormats(Model.field.TemplateName).ColumnNamesUser[i], new { @class = "form-control" })</td>
                            <td>@Html.DropDownListFor(m => Model.listOfFormats(Model.field.TemplateName).Formats[i], new SelectList(Model.formatFieldValues, "Value", "Text"), Model.listOfFormats(Model.field.TemplateName).Formats[i], new { @class = "form-control" })</td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>

            <div id="hiddenHtml" style="display:none;">
                @Html.DropDownList("FormatFieldName", new SelectList(Model.formatFieldValues, "Value", "Text"), "Domyślny", new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-success" type="button" id="addRow" style="float: right;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" id="addRow"></span></button>
            <button class="btn btn-success" id="save" style="float: left;">Zapisz</button>
            <br /><br /><br />
            <div>
                <p style="float: right;">* - Pole oznaczone gwiązdką są obowiązkowe!</p>
            </div>
            <br /> <br />
            @Html.ValidationSummary()
            <h1 style="color:@ViewBag.color">@ViewBag.Info</h1>
        }
```

Here is my model

```
public class FieldViewModel
{
    public TemplateField field { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<TemplateField> IEnumerableField;
    public Fields fieldObj {get;set;}


    public Fields listOfFormats(string nameTemplate)
    {
        Fields obj = new Fields();
        var items = IEnumerableField.Where(i => i.TemplateName == nameTemplate).ToList();
        if (items != null)
        {
            foreach (var x in items)
            {
                obj.ColumnNamesDB.Add(x.ColumnNameDB);
                obj.Formats.Add(x.Format);
                obj.LengthColumns.Add(x.Length.ToString());
                obj.ColumnNamesUser.Add(x.ColumnNameUser);
            }
        }
        return obj;
    }
}
```

and finally my controller method

```
public ActionResult addTemplate(FieldViewModel model)
{
    return ? // model is empty, there is nothing...
}
```

I think that I made some mistake in Model, can someone look at this? 
Thanks for any help!

EDIT:

Here is Fields class:

```
public class Fields
{
    public List<string> ColumnNamesDB = new List<string>();
    public List<string> LengthColumns = new List<string>();
    public List<string> Formats = new List<string>();
    public List<string> ColumnNamesUser = new List<string>();
}
```

and TemplateField cass

```
 public class TemplateField
{
    [Key]
    public int FieldId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Proszę podać nazwę kolumny z bazy danych.")]
    public string ColumnNameDB { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Proszę podać długość rekordu.")]
    public int Length { get; set; }

    public string Format { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Proszę podać nazwę szablonu.")]
    public string TemplateName { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Proszę podać nazwę kolumny jaka będzie wyświetlana.")]
    public string ColumnNameUser { get; set; }
}
```

**EDIT**

Ok I have made a lot of miastakes here so this question don't have an answer I think.

Comment: it's all due to how the `name` and `id` fields are generated for your input fields within your for loop. the names generated. Can we see the `TemplateField` `ViewModel`
Meanwhile, you can check my answer to a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22145396/binding-mvc4-to-an-object-containing-arrays/22147278#22147278

Comment: I added to my questin TemplateField and Fields @Amila

Comment: It's quite hard to give an answer using your `ViewModel`. I suggest that you don't use `Model.listOfFormats(Model.field.TemplateName)` within your view. instead, initialize `fieldObj` with data within the Get action in your controller and get rid of `public IEnumerable<TemplateField> IEnumerableField;` from you `ViewModel`
then in your view use it `fieldObj` as `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => fieldObj.ColumnNamesDB[i], new { @class = "form-control" })`

Comment: :/ i don't get it how to do it.